# After successful click that changes the page: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: ruby, jupyter-notebook, cucumber, capybara, staleelementreferenceexception

When running in a Ruby kernel on Jupyter Notebook, after finding and clicking an element that changes the page and removes the clicked element, I get this error after about 3 seconds:

[image]

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

The click itself works and I am not trying to do anything with the clicked element afterwards.  If I try to find another existing element right after the click, I do not get the above error from the first click.

The following works fine w/o any error:

```
click_button 'My Button'
find_button 'My New Button'
```

Is this expected behavior?  Why does it give an error a few seconds after the click but not if a new element is searched for right after the click?

Comment: Where are you doing this? In a running program? irb? byebug?

Comment: I would only expect it if you’re outputting (or using) the return value of the click_button call since it’s the element which is going away

Comment: can you post the unit test code here so we can debug it step by step?

Comment: I am sorry, it is not happing in a running test.  It was happening when doing initial development using Jupyter Notebook running a Ruby kernel.  The notebook must be using the return value for some time after the cell runs.  I will update the question.  Thank you for your help.